# Firestore not being recognised in my flutter project

Tags: dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Here is the error i keep recieving

E/flutter ( 6966): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

I am using

```
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
```

`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('This Works!'),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
       
           FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/oL5gfG02AjjBZ756iUT3/messages')
              .snapshots()
              .listen((event) {
            print(event);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: it says call `Firebase.initializeApp()`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the main, you should call `await Firebase.initializeApp()` like this

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Happy coding:)

Comment: Hey there successfully crossed but having this error at the DOCS that keep giving me a null not safety when i add it i still dint work "final documents = Snapshot.data.docs";

Comment: Please provide code snippets.

Comment: final documents = Snapshot.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(documents[index]['text']),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

Comment: in the itemCount, you should have `documents.length` instead of just `documents`